# SMPP Server (SMSC) emulator that accepts multiple clients

Tags: emulation, smpp

I know there's [Logica SMSC Server](http://opensmpp.logica.com/) but it doesn't respect the `address_range` parameter.

I have two clients: one with `address_range: ^123$` and another with `address_range: ^321$`. When I send an SM from 123 to 321, it gets delivered to the client that sent the SM. Is there any emulator that delivers it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SMPPSim](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/user-guide.htm#quick). You'd need a Java6 on Linux to make it work.

Get it [here](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads/SMPPSim.tar.gz)

Comment: Thank you! I don't need it now though.

Comment: link pasting is not enough, do some explaining

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: SMPPSim is not available anymore. http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/downloads.html

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the Open Source Mobicents SMSC, which supports SMPP, SIP and SS7/SIGTRAN interfaces.

https://code.google.com/p/smscgateway/
http://www.telestax.com/opensource/